# SwiftUI restrict drag gesture that changes view in TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have code that enables me to change views programatically using buttons by making use of

```
 TabView(selection: $VM.selectedPage) {

 ViewOne()
 .tag(0)
 ...
 }
```

And I am able to restrict users from progressing to the next view until user input is given, however they are still able to swipe through the views and bypass my restrictions.

I want to either add the same restrictions to the swipes as I have done with the buttons, or prevent the use of swiping to switch between views altogether.

Comment: Can you please add more code? What will happen if you just disable it?

Answer (score -1):

A bit late for the party. My suggestion is to add a custom empty `DragGesture` gesture to each subview from `TabView` with `. highPriorityGesture()` modifier so it bypasses the `TabView` behaviour.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).